# Calling Devise from a javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, bookmarklet

I have a javascript bookmarklet which used to work as a single user mode. So how it used to work is I would click on my bookmarklet on the browser, and it would inject a remote javascript on my server. This second javascript in turn makes an ajax call to my rails server with a code that looks something like this:

```
$.post(
    "http://192.168.1.2:3000/stuffs",
    {stuff: JSON.stringify({"link":address})},
    "json"
);
```

This code used to work when I was working on my project without an account. But today I added a devise authentication system. So now the system has users. In my controller code I have

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def create
    puts current_user
    @stuff.user = current_user
    ...
end
```

This doesn't work. current_user returns nothing. I am just trying to figure out whether there's an existing session (whether someone is signed in), and then want to create an entry under that user. In this case, a user has_many stuffs and stuff belongs to a user. The rest of the site works fine. It just seems trying to access using bookmarklet doesn't preserve a session.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to pass authenticity token parameter to params sent by jQuery, like this:

```
$.post(
    "http://192.168.1.2:3000/stuffs",
    {
         stuff: JSON.stringify({"link":address}), 
         authenticity_token: <%= "#{form_authenticity_token.inspect}" if protect_against_forgery? %>
    },
    "json"
);
```

More docs on `form_authenticity_token` can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-form_authenticity_token

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. First of all, I tried the same thing with GET request and it doesn't work either. I am informed that rails checks for CSRF only for PUT, POST, and DELETE. Moreover, I have even deleted the protect_from_forgery line from my controller code and it still doesn't' work.

Comment: By the way, this is unrelated to the question but, could you teach me how I can use the erb format like you mentioned, if I am calling this from a javascript bookmarklet? I know I can do it if it's included in the view inline, but this is a standalone javascript file that's being called by another javascript.